# jq shell script: aggregate iteration content into json body

Tags: shell, jq

I'm creating a shell script.

I need to create a curl json body according the a `key-value` list content. This content is splitted by way of a `awk` which generate a two column table:

```
KVS_VARIABLES=$(awk -F= '!($1 && $2 && NF==2) { print "File failed validation on line " NR | "cat 1>&2"; next } { print $1, $2 }' $f)
```

Example output:

```
VAR1 VAL1
VAR2 VAL2
VAR3 VAL3
```

So, this table is iterated on a while iteration and each `key` and `value` are splitted:

```
echo "$KVS_VARIABLES" | while read -r kv
  do
    key=$(echo $kv | awk '{print $1}')
    value=$(echo $kv | awk '{print $2}')
  done
```

So, I need some way to aggregate this content into a json document in order to send it out using `curl`:

```
curl -k \
  -X PUT \
  -d @- \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  "$SERVER_URL/api/v1/namespaces/$NAMESPACE/secrets/$SECRET_ID" <<-EOF
  {
    "kind": "Secret",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {
      "name": "$SECRET_ID"
    },
    "stringData": {
      "$key": "$value"     <<<<<<<<<<<<<(1)>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
    }
  }
EOF
```

So, on `<<<<<<<<<<<<<(1)>>>>>>>>>>>>>>` I need to aggregate each `key` and `value` propagation.`

So, in this case I'd need to generate:

```
"VAR1": "VAL1",
"VAR2": "VAL2",
"VAR3": "VAL3"
```

and then insert it inside "stringData":

```
{
    "kind": "Secret",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {
      "name": "$SECRET_ID"
    },
    "stringData": {
       <<<<<<<<<<<<<(1)>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
    }
}
```

So, after all:

```
{
    "kind": "Secret",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {
      "name": "$SECRET_ID"
    },
    "stringData": {
       "VAR1": "VAL1",
       "VAR2": "VAL2",
       "VAR3": "VAL3"
    }
}
```

`jq` is installed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *don't* need an `awk` statement inside the while loop, but just read the key value pairs inside the `read` command itself.

Also storing `awk` output in a variable and later parsing is an anti-pattern. You could use the process substitution feature provided by the shell, the `< <()` part will slurp the output of a command as if it were appearing on a file (or) use the here-strings

```
json=$(cat <<-EOF
{
    "kind": "Secret",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {
      "name": "$SECRET_ID"
    },
    "stringData": {
    }
}
EOF
)

while read -r key value; do
    json=$(echo "$json" | jq ".stringData += { \"$key\" : \"$value\" }")
done< <(awk -F= '!($1 && $2 && NF==2) { print "File failed validation on line " NR | "cat 1>&2"; next } { print $1, $2 }' $f)
```

You could now use the variable `"$json"` in the `curl` as

```
curl -k \
  -X PUT \
  -d @- \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  "$SERVER_URL/api/v1/namespaces/$NAMESPACE/secrets/$SECRET_ID" <<<"$json"
```

Comment: I'm getting stuck on this line as well: `done< <(awk -F= '!($1 && $...`. The message is `Syntax error: redirection unexpected`

Comment: @Jordi: Can you set first line to `#!/usr/bin/env bash` and run it again